# How to add Image in Spinner?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner

I made this app called UnitConverter...

```
    unitarray=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    unitarray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SpinnerUnit.setAdapter(unitarray);
    unitarray.add(getResources().getString(R.string.unit1));
    unitarray.add(getResources().getString(R.string.unit2));
    unitarray.add(getResources().getString(R.string.unit3));
    unitarray.add(getResources().getString(R.string.unit4));
    unitarray.add(getResources().getString(R.string.unit5));
    unitarray.add(getResources().getString(R.string.unit6));
    unitarray.add(getResources().getString(R.string.unit7));
    unitarray.add(getResources().getString(R.string.unit8));
    unitarray.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

everything's awesome but I want to put images next to each Unit!
is there anyone who can help me with this please? thanks!

Comment: you have to create an costum adapter

Comment: If all images are the same you don't need a custom adapter, you can just use a custom layout for each row of the spinner.

Comment: no, they're not the same! and thank y'all :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way would be to use android's R.layout.simple_spinner_item as the spinner elem layout and internally to add an image to the TextView using [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);
countrySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And the adapter:

```
class ImageSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        Elem elem = elemArray.get(position);
        textView.setText(elem.toString());
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(elem.getImage(), null, null, null);
        return textView;
    }
}
```

See detailed example [here.](http://spweblog.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/this-post-was-inspried-by-request-i.html)